# Converting VB6 to PHP

Tags: php, vb6

I'm working on a little project converting some VB6 code to PHP just for fun. I'm at a stand still because I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be convert this set of code into PHP or even if it's possible. I'm taking this code: https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=62118&lngWId=1&txtForceRefresh=102520191942345723 and seeing if it's possible to have the OSCAR protocol connect to a PHP socket. I've had some success but I'm stuck.

So the code in VB6 I'm trying to move over to PHP is this:

`FlapVersion = ChrB("00 00 00 01")`

There's a few other things such as:

`SNAC = ChrB("00 03 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00")`

`BuddyDeparted = SNAC & SByte(sScreenName) & ChrB("00 00 00 01 00 01 00 02 00 00")`

I've looked all over and come up with nothing, I'm not even sure if it's possible to convert the ChrB calls into PHP.

Comment: You might get more relevant attention if you tagged this Q with "PHP" as well as VB6

Comment: ChrB [probably returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa262692(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) the ASCII character. Not sure what the PHP function is for that.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your code closer. You will find a function somewhere called `ChrB` that accepts a string argument and returns a string.

Calling the common `ChrB` VB6 function with a string will throw a type mismatch because the VB6 `ChrB` function expects a byte argument.

Once you find the `ChrB` function, you can work on converting whatever it's doing to your PHP implementation.

VB6 lets you implement what looks like a feature name, unfortunately without an error or warning, because it's not a language feature here, it's just a function being provided, in this case, from the MSVBVM60.DLL library.  So you have your own function within scope that this is calling, it's not calling the 'regular' `ChrB` function.